# Resources to start with <topic> - ideas for blog link collections 

Tags: discussion, blog

@yossarian proposed a great idea in chat: Make collections of links curated by our community members.

There was a discussion about whether we should explain some really basic stuff like "How to stir fry" on the blog. Argument against: We create no new value if we endlessly repeat what is already widely available elsewhere. Argument for: community members who just do a Google search for an area they haven't experimented with, like "tofu making", don't know which hits are good, but they would trust a post written by our members who are known for a rep in this area.

The new series has the potential to be the best of two worlds. Those of us who have become an expert in an area fondly remember the informations sources which helped them along the way, and want to pass this information on. If it is freely available, it is enough to link to it, instead of investing the effort to write it from the beginning. But when they recommend the links, then our average reader can trust the links as much as he trusts a post written by the member who proposed it.

This thread is the place for you, our readership, to tell us what areas you are interested in. Tell us what link collections you would like to see, which ones will help you in your daily cooking. Everybody who notices a topic he has good links for, can mail us the link at cooking.se.blog@gmail.com, and when we have a big enough collection, we will publish it. Alternatively, some of you may already have a good collection on a single topic - then use the same address to tell us about it, and we will make a post out of it.

This kind of post will be published as an addition to our regular posts. It won't require writing a lengthy text with pictures the way the regular posts do. 7-8 links with a sentence or two for each, explaining why it is good, will suffice.

This thread will also let us judge which beginner topics also need a good post from us. For now, we know that bread hydration experiments and oven steam injectors are rare on the Internet, and assume that guides to making tofu are plentiful. But if we can't find good tofu links, and nobody supplies them, and all tofu links we find are lacking in some way, we will consider making our own post on the topic.

Comment: I think this could also be a way to try to elevate the quality of answers, depending on how it is done, and aid in the pursuit of those evasive canonical answers. If any of the other stacks are doing this, could you link to some pre-existing content in this regard?

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but something to keep in mind: will anyone be reviewing these "link collection" blog posts on a regular basis (every few months or so) to make sure that none of the links are dead? Content on the internet moves around a lot - we don't want to wind up with a collection of only semi-useful links.

Answer (score 1):

Coffee sourcing, methods, preparation, brewing, and storage